# Why was Edo Tensei Madara young, when he had died at an old age?

Tags: naruto

From *Naruto* manga and anime, I know that Uchiha Madara died as an old person after he helped Uchiha Obito.

But it was bit weird for me, when Kabuto summoned Uchiha Madara-sama with Edo Tensei, Madara was a younger person.

Again, when Chiyo was summoned, she was older as when she died.

How can it be possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can read [here](http://naruciak.wikia.com/wiki/Kuchiyose:_Edo_Tensei) that:

> The reincarnated can also have their bodies modified and experimented on. **While the technique usually reincarnates one as they were upon death, the reincarnated can also have various points from their life combined to get the best possible results as seen with Madara Uchiha**, having been brought back "beyond his prime" despite dying a withered old man. In addition to regaining his physical youth with peak health and combat prowess, he also retained the Wood Release and Rinnegan abilities he had in his old age.